# REGEX Parameters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a notepad with data that looks like this:

```
"$7.49"
"$124.00"
"$530.00"
```

How can I search through a range using regular expressions like 200-1000, but that values must be in `"$XXX.XX"` format.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you precise the meaning of *scanning through*? Do you want to match `$7.49`, `$124.00`... ?

Comment: I'm sorry for being too innacurate. I wanna scan through a range like between 250-1000, but that values are in "$XXX.XX" format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with $XXX.XX `\$\d+\.\d+`. The problem with ranges are that numbers used in 3 digits bleed over to 4 digits and the regex gets way more complicated.

Use regex sets `[ ]`  to limit the numbers/values.

So I would search for similar digits such as 200-999.xx which would be

`\$[2-9]\d\d\.\d\d`

or for four digits for 1000-1500

`\$1[1-5]\d\d\.\d\d`

Comment: Lovely it only scans through what I want, but how can I add a range to the values that are being filtered?

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily manipulate numbers through regular expressions. It's doable though, so let's look at what you want to have.

1. Numbers are in the form `\d+\.\d+`, with no preceding zeroes.
2. You want to match numbers superior or equal to 200.
3. You want to match numbers lower or equal to 1000.

So, we have to look at our numbers like they are strings of characters. With the exception of `1000`, all of those have three digits. So your regex is something like:

```
\$([2-9]\d\d\.\d\d|1000\.00)
```

That is, "a number with three digits left to the dot and the first one is `2` or higher or 1000.00".

Comment: I seldom use an *or* because my patterns are so focused (to not create any backtracking) that I sometimes forget its usage. I liked the alternative you provided. +1

Answer (score 0):

If by range you mean number of digits, then go: `\$\d{1,3}\,\d{1,2}`